# What's a good chemistry book for a practical man

Tags: experimental-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, books

Yesterday I picked up my old organic chemistry book and started to read it from the first chapter. After a couple of minutes I realized that I don't understand the concepts at all.

The first chapter mentions the reason behind polarity of covalant bonds because of difference in electronegativity of different elements, flourine being the highest. Now chemistry is a practical science and all these concepts have been theorized by observing reactions. Is there a chemistry book which gives a detailed explanation of the experiments which led to the formulation of theories we read in school?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. This is far too broad of a question and isn't really appropriate for our site. For starters, I would look at a general chemistry book before an organic book, and go from there. If you don't have one, check our list for some guidance, and try some videos too: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry